# How to Use Rotativa Asp Net Core mvc in linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, rotativa

When i try to use Rotativa in asp net core mvc in linux - Ubuntu 18.04 , I have this issue:

```
Exception: QPainter::begin(): Returned false Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

In the controller I have this:

```cs
public IActionResult Utilidad(string fecha) {

  var fechas = fecha.Split('-');

  var ventasGeneradas = _ventaRepository.GetListado();

  var modelo = new VentaBaseViewModel() {
    ListaVentas = ventasGeneradas
  };

  return new ViewAsPdf("Utilidad", modelo) {

};

}
```

In the startup I have this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    // app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
  }
  else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
  });

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  });

  Rotativa.AspNetCore.RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");

}
```

I have already installed the package `Rotativa.AspNetCore --version 1.2.0-beta` and in the folder Rotativa inside `wwwRoot` I have `wkhtmltoimage` and `wkhtmltopdf`.

I am using NetCore version 5.0

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: It could work well in my project.Did you miss sharing the message?What is the error?Something like:`QPainter::begin(): Returned false Error: Unable to write to destination
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.`

Comment: DIsclaimer: I'm the author of Rotativa.AspNetCore and also the creator of the SaaS service rotativa.io. If you want to avoid any issues with wkhtmltopdf running on the server you can use rotativa.io that just needs the ability to do HTTP calls. The service has a limited free subscription and paid plans for bigger loads.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found that upgrading to 5.0.403 from an earlier version of .NET SDK was all that was required to make this bug go away. [I got my hint to try an upgrade from here.](https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore/issues/46)